# Ant can't find XML file using a relative path to an external entity

Tags: xml, ant, path

I have an `XML` that refers to an others `XML` files with relative paths to a external entity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//Dawid Weiss//DTD DocBook V3.1-Based Extension for XML and graphics inclusion//EN" "../../dtd/oceandocx.dtd" [
<!ENTITY capitulo_uno SYSTEM "capitulo_uno.xml">
]>
```

That works fine in `ant 1.7.1`, but when I use a newer version of `ant (1.9.2)` I get this error:

```
Fatal Error! Failure reading file:d://home//git//src//en//xml//index.xml 
Cause: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: capitulo_uno.xml
```

I checked there shouldn't be a problem referring to a file like this, but in other posts says that it should work adding "file:".

When I use the full path works

```
<!ENTITY capitulo_uno SYSTEM "file:d://home//git//src//en//xml//capitulo_ch.xml">
```

but I need to use a relative path, I tried with these but no success

```
<!ENTITY capitulo_uno SYSTEM "capitulo_uno.xml">
```

.

```
<!ENTITY capitulo_uno SYSTEM "file://capitulo_uno.xml">
```

.

```
<!ENTITY capitulo_uno SYSTEM "file:///capitulo_uno.xml">
```

.

```
<!ENTITY capitulo_uno SYSTEM "file:.//capitulo_uno.xml">
```

The XML files are in the same folder. 
Don't know if it's a problem with this version of ant or I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you use "file://./capitulo_uno.xml" to have . represent current directory?  Sorry just saw the last entry!

Comment: I tried with it but error reading the xml instead the exception.

Comment: One solution is to change to a previous version of ant 1.7.1. But ill try to find the solution because I use  1.9.2 for other stuff

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The relative path seems to start at the directory the ant buildfile is in.

Folder setup:

project/ant_buildfile.xml

project/input/combined.xml

project/input/part1.xml

Goal:

combined.xml should include the part1.xml.

The reference in the combined.xml looks like this then:

"file:./input/part1.xml"